# jquery autocomplete on last word

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to edit this js code so that the autocomplete function kicks in after each `non-breaking space`; regardless of whether or not the text entered before each `non-breaking space` was one of the tags. So, for example, if I enter PHP, that's one of the tags. But, if for the next text that I enter, it must be one of the tags too otherwise anything that I enter after PHP will not activate the autocomplete. You can find this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLGCQ/)

Comment: [Actual readable code for anyone interested](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/BLGCQ/1/).

Comment: Yes, sorry about the mess of a code. But, the autocomplete function still doesn't work unless all of what's entered has been selected from the autocomplete drop down list as one of the tags. I kinda need this to work like the way it does on fb where you can tag a person at any point in the textarea.

Comment: I don't see the point of re-iterating your problem; all I did is format the code, as my post explained.  Next time, be sure to click the 'tidy up' button in js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're looking for a plugin like this one:

http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html
- or -
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Basically you need to look for "jQuery Autocomplete Tags" instead of just "jQuery Autocomplete".

Comment: Um. the first one is good. But, I don't want it to be so that every word entered becomes a tag. only if the word entered is one of the accepted values that is defined in the jquery code.

Comment: What is your goal, with a real world example, that you're trying to achieve ? Is it a search box ? A combo box ? A check list, radio buttons ? What is your HTML Fallback and desired user experience ?

Comment: Well, this whole problem came about when I found out that anchor tags aren't supported inside of textareas. This code is going to be applied to a textarea that a user uses to edit an article. But, I want the user to be able to tag other articles there as well.

Comment: Can you please write a quick JSfiddle how would a functional HTML look like, without the JavaScript ? I think that would be the first step :)